# Cython: Initialize Structured Numpy Array ValueError

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

I want to use Cython to speed up my Python code in analogy to the [Cython's Numpy tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/0.14/src/tutorial/numpy.html). I give you a MWE of what I intended:

Test Function:

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
import CythonModule2 as cm2

print cm2.read_data()
```

Cython Module `CythonModule2.pyx`:

```
from libc.stdio cimport *
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef packed struct CData:
    np.float32_t A
    np.uint8_t CH1, CH2
    np.int64_t D

def read_data():
    cdef np.ndarray[CData] coins = np.empty(10, dtype=[('A', 'f4'),
                                                       ('CH1', '|u1'), ('CH2', '|u1'),
                                                       ('D', '<i8')])
    return coins;
```

The definition in the function `read_data()` produces the following error message (and C++ "terminated in an unusual way"):

> ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch; next field is at offset 6 but 8 expected

I could format all entries in 64bit (eight byte) variables but I want to keep the data as small as possible in order to save space.

By the way: My computers setup is as following:

- Windows 7 64bit
- 32bit Python(x,y) 2.7.6
- MinGW's compiler `mingw32-gcc-4.8.1`.
- Cython version 0.23.2
- Numpy version 1.10.0

I think it is not the same error as in the previous question since I updated Cython: [Passing a structured numpy array with strings to a cython function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21435378/2062965)

#### Edit

By compiling the module with `distutils` there is the same error displayed. When executing the function, the above error occurs.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules = cythonize('CythonModule2.pyx'))
import CythonModule2 as cm2
print cm2.read_data()
```

#### Edit 2: Output files

There is no file called `CythonModule2.pyd`. The created files (`CythonModule2.c`, `CythonModule2.def`, `CythonModule2.o`) are stored in the following location:

> C:\Users\Myself.pyxbld\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyrex\

Comment: `u1` is unicode, which is 3 or 4 bytes.

Comment: So that means I should rewrite the line with `CH1` and `CH2`? The problem still exists if I remove them from `CData` and the definition. Do you have another idea about the `float` and `int`?

Comment: I updated Numpy to version 1.10.0 but the problem was not solved.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook `u1` for `U1`.  It is the `uint8` that you expected.

Answer (score 0):

> GCC: 5.2
>
> Cython: 0.23.2
>
> Python: 2.7.10
>
> Numpy: 1.9.2
>
> OS: Linux

With my environment all works fine. The result of running script:

```
[(1.5573903757535362e+29, 155, 127, 9195066190654341120)
 (7.709522375552512e+37, 229, 106, 7556991212100550555)
 (4.57762169340988e-41, 176, 211, 9056738852782958815)
 (nan, 0, 0, 140305456158120)
 (8.456264184549564e+24, 155, 127, 9195058375810875392)
 (-98784247808.0, 223, 104, 753066985721462683)
 (0.04620097950100899, 65, 0, 7696651763176177664)
 (38982272417792.0, 0, 0, 140305575418824)
 (0.04620097950100899, 61, 61, 4412750543122677053)
```

Comment: I am still using Numpy version 1.9.1 and the gcc 4.8.1 (which is the most recent one for Windows). It could be the case that I did something wrong with the configuration of my MinGW.

Comment: Can you pastebin your generated CythonModule2.c file? I want compare it with mine.

Comment: I uploaded the generated file `CythonModule2.c` on http://pastebin.com/aZmGURMs so you can check with your version.

Comment: Files is very similar. Also I compile your *.c file without any problem. It's just a guess, but what if you install 64bit python version?